# Add custom properties to ASP.net checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Checkbox list items have default "Text", "Value", "Enabled" and "Selected" properties.

I need to add an "ImageUrl" property to each item in my list.
I use this code:

```
foreach (Zone zn in ZonesList)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem(zn.Name, zn.Id.ToString());
    item.Attributes.Add("ImageUrl", zn.Image );
    item.Selected = false;

    visitPlaceList.Items.Add(item);
}

visitPlaceList.DataBind();
```

but it still doesn't show any properties other than the defaults.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is the purpose of adding these properties? If it's just to retrieve the value later, you can use ````data-imageUrl```` or something similar like that.  But if you're wanting the ListItem to have an Image then you need to rethink your approach.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @JohnPete22 Yes, I need each item to show his image beside. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you are limited with the ASP:Checkbox.  You could try an ASP:Repeater if you need to use an ASP control, and for each row you could have a label as well as an image.  It would take more work, but you'd get the desired effect.

Comment: Or you could try a non-ASP checkbox (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp) where they are linked via name attribute, but you can have other HTML in between them (i.e. images).

Answer (score 1):

A property does get added, but as a `span` element surrounding the input and label. It looks like this

```
<span imageurl="www.google.nl">
    <input id="ctl00_mainContentPane_visitPlaceList_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContentPane$visitPlaceList$1" />
    <label for="ctl00_mainContentPane_visitPlaceList_1">Name 1</label>
</span>
```

So if you need it with jQuery, get the correct element.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="visitPlaceList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:CheckBoxList>

<script>
    $("#visitPlaceList input").change(function () {
        var imageurl = $(this).closest('span').attr('imageurl');
        console.log(imageurl);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question! It exposes the limitations that web controls sometimes have.

I believe the proper way to solve it is by [creating a custom (web) control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/893667/overview-of-user-controls-vs-custom-controls). It is far from trivial though especially since both `ListItem` and `CheckBoxList` are sealed classes.

It can also be solved by creating a user control (ascx). The following can be improved but you get the idea:

**ImageCheckBoxList.ascx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**ImageCheckBoxList.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class ImageCheckBoxList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public IList<ImageListItem> Items { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = Items;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var checkBox = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (checkBox != null)
            {
                Items[i].Checked = checkBox.Checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `ImageListItem` is:

```
public class ImageListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public ImageListItem(string text, string value, string imageUrl)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it in a Web Forms page:

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ImageCheckBoxList" Src="ImageCheckBoxList.ascx" %>

<uc:ImageCheckBoxList ID="ImageCheckBoxList1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageCheckBoxList1.Items = new List<ImageListItem>()
    {
        new ImageListItem("Item 1", "Item1", "Images/1.png"),
        new ImageListItem("Item 2", "Item2", "Images/2.png"),
        new ImageListItem("Item 3", "Item3", "Images/3.png")
    };
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ImageListItem item in ImageCheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Checked)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{item.Text} with value {item.Value} is checked.");
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```